# mean returns NaN besides na.rm= TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr

**Sample data**

```
date        coins   
2013-10-01  NA      
2013-10-01  NA      
2013-10-01  NA      
2013-11-01  10      
2013-11-01  NA      
2013-11-01  20      
2013-11-01  30      
2013-11-01  40      
2013-12-30  NA      
2013-12-30  22      
2013-12-30  24
2013-12-30  25
```

**What I want to do?**

I want to calculate mean and median of the coins column, ignoring missing values.

**What i have done so far?**

1. Grouped the data on date variable `by_date <- group_by(df, date)`
2. Summarised data using:`by_date %>% summarise_each_(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE), median(., na.rm=TRUE)), names(by_date)[2])`

**Question**
The results returned by summarise_each_ show **NaN** for date **2013-10-01**. Does that mean the function is not ignoring missing values?

Comment: it means you're doing this `mean(NA, na.rm = TRUE)` you can set a check if all values for a group are NA then use na.rm = FALSE

Comment: As a side note, instead of `... summarise_each_(funs(...), names(by_date)[2])` you can use `... summarise_each(funs(...), 2)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks for the suggestion, but as i change the argument as you suggested R responds with the error `Error in UseMethod("as.lazy_dots") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.lazy_dots' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Comment: @ImranAli, you have to use `summarise_each`, not `summarise_each_` with my suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that all the values for 2013-10-01 are `NA`, so there can't be a mean.  The `NaN` is R trying to tell you this.

If you'd rather just not have 2013-10-01 show up in the summary, one option is to get rid of `NA` values upfront like this:

```
by_date<-group_by(df[!is.na(df$coins),],date)
```

Comment: A pointer to readers: [R: Why does mean(NA, na.rm = TRUE) return NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51503869/4891738).