# Why does mean(NA, na.rm = TRUE) return NaN

Tags: r, nan, mean, na

When estimating the mean with a vector of all NA's we get an `NaN` if `na.rm = TRUE`. Why is this, is this flawed logic or is there something I'm missing? Surely it would make more sense to use `NA` than `NaN`?

Quick example below

```
mean(NA, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] NaN

mean(rep(NA, 10), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] NaN
```

Comment: Because you then have a vector of length zero and a division by zero is `NaN`. As for whether it makes more sense, I believe it doesn't, since you have removed the missing values.

Comment: Because you have nothing left. `mean(numeric(0))`

Comment: Note that `mean(as.Date(NA), na.rm = TRUE)` is NA and not NaN though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bit pity that `?mean` does not say anything about this. [My comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503869/why-does-meanna-na-rm-t-return-nan#comment89976523_51503869) only told you that applying `mean` on an empty "numeric" results in `NaN` without more reasoning. [Rui Barradas's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503869/why-does-meanna-na-rm-t-return-nan#comment89976520_51503869) tried to reason this but was not accurate, as division by `0` is not always `NaN`, it can be `Inf` or `-Inf`. I once discussed about this in [R: element-wise matrix division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39519913/4891738). However, we are getting close. Although `mean(x)` is not coded by `sum(x) / length(x)`, this mathematical fact really explains this `NaN`.

From `?sum:`

```
 *NB:* the sum of an empty set is zero, by definition.
```

So `sum(numeric(0))` is `0`. As `length(numeric(0))` is `0`, `mean(numeric(0))` is `0 / 0` which is `NaN`.

Comment: Further reading on `NaN`: [In R, why does is.numeric(NaN) print “TRUE”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44602252/4891738). Also, readers should  understand that `median(numeric(0))` gives `NA`, `min(numeric(0))` gives `Inf`, and `max(numeric(0))` gives `-Inf`. Why they behave as such is explained in documentation page `?median` and `?min`.

Answer (score 2):

From `mean` documentation :

> na.rm     a logical value indicating whether NA values should be
>   stripped before the computation proceeds.

With this logic all NAs are removed before the function mean is applied. In your cases you are applying mean to nothing (all NAs are removed) so NaN is returned.

Comment: I believe it wont return `NULL` because r still recognizes the vector as numeric even though it contains all missing values. For example this will throw a warning even though you remove the `NA` value: `mean(c(NA_character_),na.rm = TRUE)`. Interesting point on the `numeric(0)` though.