# Append one row with average values for selected columns and counting percent for another based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a `df` below, I need to calculate `Pass` percent after excluding `-` rows and the average values of `pred1` and `pred2`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 
  status = c('Pass', 'Fail', '-', 'Pass', 'Pass'), 
  real = c(10, NA, 8, 9, 4), 
  pred1 = c(50, 20, NA, 14, 11),
  pred2 = c(12, 12, 8, NA, 6)
)
```

df:

```
  name status real pred1 pred2
1    A   Pass   10    50    12
2    B   Fail   NA    20    12
3    C      -    8    NA     8
4    D   Pass    9    14    NA
5    E   Pass    4    11     6
```

**The expected result:**

```
  name status real pred1 pred2
1    A   Pass   10    50    12
2    B   Fail   NA    20    12
3    C      -    8    NA     8
4    D   Pass    9    14    NA
5    E   Pass    4    11     6
6 total  0.75   NA 23.75   9.5
```

I thought to bind to the result below to `df`, but it's not concise and beautiful solutions:

```
pass_percent <- nrow(df %>% filter(status == 'Pass')) / nrow(df %>% filter(status != '-'))
avg_pred1 <- mean(df$pred1, na.rm = T)
avg_pred2 <- mean(df$pred2, na.rm = T)
```

How could I achieve that in one conciser way with R's pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `tibble::add_row`:

```r
df %>% 
  add_row(name = "total",
          status = as.character(mean(df$status[df$status != "-"] == "Pass")),
          real = mean(df$real),
          pred1 = mean(df$pred1, na.rm = T),
          pred2 = mean(df$pred2, na.rm = T))

   name status real pred1 pred2
1     A   Pass   10 50.00  12.0
2     B   Fail   NA 20.00  12.0
3     C      -    8    NA   8.0
4     D   Pass    9 14.00    NA
5     E   Pass    4 11.00   6.0
6 total   0.75   NA 23.75   9.5
```

Explanation of `as.character(mean(df$status[df$status != "-"] == "Pass"))`:

- `df$status[df$status != "-"]` is the vector of `df$status` without the element equal to `"-"` (so only `Pass` and `Fail`).
- `df$status[df$status != "-"] == "Pass"` is `TRUE` if `df$status` is `"Pass"`, `FALSE` otherwise.
- `mean(...)` is possible because TRUE and FALSE values are coerced to numeric when the mean is computed.
- `as.character(...)` is needed because `df$status` is a character variable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, much conciser. May i ask why we could use `status = as.character(mean(df$status[df$status != "-"] == "Pass"))` to calculate percent of `Pass` number?

Comment: Is it possible to use `rbind()` as well?

Comment: See my edit. hope it's clearer :)

Comment: @ahbon with rbind, use `rbind(c(...))`

Comment: After I've converted your code to a function, then use `lapply`, it seems not working out. Do you think this method is suitable for a function? :(

Comment: It should work fine yes. Maybe with `rbind`?

Comment: Some of `total`s are `NaN` or `NA`, I think the problem is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503869/r-why-does-meanna-na-rm-true-return-nan

Answer (score 1):

Not as concise as @Mael but a different take:

```
df %>% 
  bind_rows(
    data.frame(name = "total") %>% 
      bind_cols(df %>% 
         summarise(across(matches("pred"), list(~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), .names = "{.col}"),
            status = as.character(mean(status[status != "-"] == "Pass")))))
#    name status real pred1 pred2
# 1     A   Pass   10 50.00  12.0
# 2     B   Fail   NA 20.00  12.0
# 3     C      -    8    NA   8.0
# 4     D   Pass    9 14.00    NA
# 5     E   Pass    4 11.00   6.0
# 6 total   0.75   NA 23.75   9.5
```